# Make a game written in Javascript available online

Tags: javascript, adobe

I've just finished a simple game in Adobe Animate using the HTML5 Canvas. I now have .fla, .html and .js files. Can I now put these somewhere on my website to make the game available to play? If so, where? If not, what else do I need? Thanks.

Clicking on the HTML file opens it in a browser, but I can't interact with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're stepping in to a whole new world of hosting and deployments. To have a functioning website you need:

- A host server
- A domain name
- Web files (which you have)

The host server will serve up your web files and allow incoming traffic from the web.

The domain name is optional, but helps with visibility. Without it you'll have to connect directly to the IP address of the host server.

I'd recommend finding a host like HostGator, GoDaddy, or [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) if you want to host a static website. It can be pretty intimidating at first, but you'll need to put in the time reading documentation to fully understand the process.

Alternatively, if you just want to get it running locally and not on the internet you can install a simple http server on your machine. I use NodeJS so I'll test with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) alot. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I should have been more specific. The game is for pupils to play at the school I work at. I'd like them to be able to play it on their iPads and for the teacher to be able to access it on their laptops. We have a hosted website, so if there's a way it could go on there, that might work, or if there's just a way I can create a shortcut to the files in SharePoint maybe? Why doesn't the game play properly when I open the HTML file?

Comment: The game doesn't play properly because you're not viewing a 'webpage', you're viewing a rendered HTML file. You need to be running a web server in order for the assets (like JS files) to run properly. You could embed the JS directly into your HTML with script tags, otherwise you need a server.

Comment: A shortcut to the files in SharePoint is not going to work for the same reasons. There's a difference between an HTML file and a webpage. You mention you have a hosted website, and yes you could put it there, you just need to host your files in the same location as your existing website. For example, if you have "myschool.com", you could put your files at the root of where that domain is pointing. Then you could navigate to "myschool.com/mygame.html"